# How to resume/continue from already trained YOLO5 Training Epoch?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, yolo, yolov5

I have started the Yolo5 Training with custom data

The command I have used:

```
!python train.py --img 640 --batch-size 32 --epochs 5 --data /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov5_dataset/dataset_Trafic/data.yaml --cfg /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov5/models/yolov5s.yaml  --name Model
```

Training started as below & completed:

[image]

For resuming/continue for more epoch I have below command

```
!python train.py --img 640 --batch-size 32 --epochs 6 --data /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov5_dataset/dataset_Trafic/data.yaml --weights /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov5/runs/train/Model/weights/best.pt --cache --exist-ok
```

[image]

But still the Training start from the scratch. How to continue from previous epoch.

Also I tried with resume command

```
!python train.py --epochs 10 --resume
```

but I am getting below error message

[image]

Comment: When you specify a weight in command, it initialize network weighs with specified weight file. So it does not start from scratch. Only the number of epochs starts from zero.

Comment: Thanks.But if we compare the time taken for each epoch , there is no much difference between these two methods/command

Comment: Time taken for each epoch depends on your data and your model. So if you don't change them, duration of epoch won't change

Comment: Found few solution from video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9WS5jga0Lg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work for YOLOv5 but this is how to resume training in YOLOv8 from the [documentation](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/train/):

#### Python

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO('path/to/last.pt')  # load a partially trained model
results = model.train(resume=True)
```

#### CLI

```
yolo train resume model=path/to/last.pt
```

Answer (score 2):

Open `runs/train/Model/opt.yaml` file and change epochs no.
try again

```
!python train.py  --weights /content/drive/MyDrive/yolov5/runs/train/Model/weights/last.pt  --resume
```

Comment: The provided solution is not clear for readers. Please, clarify it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This works for YOLOv7 too

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In the runs folder(where your previous weights are stored), find a file with name "args.yaml" inside the file, augment the epochs count by the no. of epochs you want to train your model now.
For example:
If previously your model was trained for 100 epochs then, the args.yaml file would have an attribute:
"epochs: 100"
Lets say you was to continue training for 50 more epochs then change epochs to 150 i.e.
"epochs: 150"
save the file and then execute training command.